# Writing to partially reserved registers of sensors

Tags: sensors, bit, registers

I'm trying to change the range of a gyroscope I'm using and there is the following guideline:

> it is recommended to mask out
> (logical and with zero) reserved bits of registers which are partially marked as reserved.

I tried reading about bit masking with the bitwise operators and I feel I understand it for trying to read only certain bits, but not for writing.

For example, how would I write to the following register, masking out the 2 bits which are reserved?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always write a whole byte when you set the register. You only need to "mask out" those bits if there's a danger that you may inadvertently set them to 1, for instance through some value over flow from other bits when combining values together to form that byte.

If you're not doing that then there's nothing to mask out.  For instance if you just want to set a specific set of bits then just set that value - `0b00101001` is going to be `0b00101001` whether you mask it or not.

If you decide you *really* want to mask a value, for instance if you are writing a library and you have no control over what an end user may decide to pass to a function, then `&` (or `&=`) is your friend:

```cpp
uint8_t val = 0x55; // 0b01010101 in binary
val &= 0b00111111; // or 0x3F if you want to use HEX
// val is now 0x15 since bit 6 has been "masked" to 0.
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative answer. In your example, do you mean bit 7 and bit 8 are masked out?

Comment: 6 and 7. You start counting bits from 0.

Comment: Thank you again :)